# How do I stroke a knocked out object?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

In HTML5 canvas I'm trying to knock out an object with another object and stroke the final product of this operation. Is that possible at all? I'm using the following code with no success:

```
var tcan = document.getElementById('test');
var tctx = tcan.getContext('2d');

tctx.beginPath();

tctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
tctx.fillRect(0,0,70,70);

tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

tctx.fillRect(20,20,70,70);
tctx.closePath();

tctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0'; // expecting the final product to have a yellow stroke
tctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/x8Maf/

[image]

You can use source-atop compositing to draw your yellow stroke only atop your existing knockout:

```
tctx.beginPath();

tctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
tctx.fillRect(0,0,70,70);

// knock-out compositing
tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

tctx.fillRect(20,20,70,70);
tctx.closePath();

// composite where new drawings appear only where overlapping existing
tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

tctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0'; // expecting the final product to have a yellow stroke
tctx.lineWidth=2;
tctx.strokeRect(20,20,70,70);

// restore the default compositing
tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

A couple of hints:

- You don't need beginPath if you use fillRect or strokeRect (these commands automatically beginPath for you);
- All canvas strokes are half-inside and half-outside the specified dimensions.  So fillRect(20,20,70,70) will actually stroke from 19.50 to 20.50.

**[ Addition to answer: Here's how to stroke the knockout shape. ]**

```
var tcan = document.getElementById('test');
var tctx = tcan.getContext('2d');

tctx.lineWidth=2;
tctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0'; 

tctx.fillStyle = '#F00';
tctx.fillRect(50,50,70,70);
tctx.strokeRect(50,50,70,70);

// knock-out compositing
tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

tctx.fillRect(70,70,70,70);
tctx.closePath();

// composite where new drawings appear only where overlapping existing
tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop";

tctx.lineWidth=4;
tctx.strokeRect(70,70,70,70);

// restore the default compositing
tctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however the code you kindly provided does not work as expected. The stroke was drawn only on two inner edges of the shape, even when I increased `lineWidth` to a significantly larger value so to better see the effect. I also replaced `.strokeRect()` with `stroke()` - to no avail.

Comment: I thought you wanted a yellow stroke just on the bottom-right edge?  If you wanted to stroke the entire knocked out shape I've added that solution to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were faster than launching the Illustrator on my machine... This was exactly what I was after.

Comment: More like sectors of a donut. I aim at being able to have a sector of a donut filled with a color or stroked only. This being the closest I could find quickly on the internet: http://www.conceptdraw.com/samples/resource/images/solutions/project-management-diagrams/Project-Management-Radial-Tasks-Diagram.png. I'm trying to weigh between doing it in raw canvas or using Raphael. Meanwhile I appreciate your wizardry, will get back to it tomorrow! Kudos!

Comment: with some artifacts, but close to what I want http://jsfiddle.net/nutondev/Hs3kg/1/

Comment: @Artur Here's a "fake" stroked arc which is really created from a wider yellow outer arc and a narrower red inner arc:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Ma59M/

Comment: your example simply rocks and it's impossible to overestimate your help in educating me :) Thanks a bunch! Meanwhile I transferred the project to kinetic.js as I decided I might need events at some point. Now it's time for some 'back-to-school' hours with geometry. BTW, I found an easier way to draw the subtracted wedges by sequencing two `.arc` method directly one after another with opposite `clockwise` parameter.